# GhostDoc "Document this" not working for method with attribute

Tags: xml-comments, ghostdoc

I am using GhostDoc and Visual Studio 2017.

Now, if I have a method like this

```cs
public string Foo() { ... }
```

I can normally use GhostDocs "Document this" to generate an XML comment for the relevant method.

However, if the method has any attributes applied to it, e.g.

```cs
[NotNull]
public string Foo() { ... }
```

GhostDoc **cannot automatically** document the method. Why is that? Since fairly all of my methods are annotated, being unable to use GhostDoc is not very comfortable.

- **Is there any way that GhostDoc can document methods with attributes?**

---

And by the way: I tried to add the comments manually by inserting `///` *between* the attribute and the method, which yields a

> XML comment is not placed on a valid language element

error.

[image]

however, if I insert the `///` *before* the attribute, I don't get the error. I feel like even when adding the `///` *between* the method and attribute, the comment is applied to the *method* and should therefore be placed on a valid language element, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serge from SubMain is here.

We tried to reproduce the issue you reporting and GhostDoc generated the docs fine.

Could you please send us GhostDoc log files for troubleshooting?  You will find the log files in \SubMain\GhostDoc {Edition} for VSxxxx*.log

Please send the logs at support at submain dot com.

If you include the production version and edition that would be very helpful.

We look forward to working with you to troubleshoot the issue you are experiencing!

Thanks!

Comment: Weird enough, when I wanted to reproduce the issue again today, I couldn't. Might be because of the VS update... nevertheless, thank you for your answer and your willingness to help.

Comment: My pleasure! I'm glad GhostDoc is working for you again!